# Pasar una instruccion de sql a un asp:SqlDataSource

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Tengo la siguiente sentencia probada en el sql server:

```
select AsignaturaNombre from Asignatura where CodigoAsignatura=(SELECT [idMateria] FROM [Permisos] WHERE ([idProfesor] = 19398676) union SELECT [idMateria] FROM [Permisos] WHERE ([idAlumno] = 19398676))
```

Pero al momento de pasar a sentencia al `sqldatasource` de la siguiente manera:

```
<h5>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Selecione la materia "></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="idMateria" DataValueField="idMateria">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UMAConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select AsignaturaNombre from Asignatura where CodigoAsignatura=(SELECT [idMateria] FROM [Permisos] WHERE ([idProfesor] = @idAlumno) union SELECT [idMateria] FROM [Permisos] WHERE ([idAlumno] = @idAlumno))">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="idAlumno" SessionField="Codigo" Type="Double" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</h5>
```

Pero me dice que no reconoce la instrucción y salta una excepción:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'idMateria'.

¿Cómo puedo colocar esa sentencia?

Comment: No pusiste el código donde haces el binding, pero supongo que tienes un campo que se llama `idMateria` en tu gridview, y este no es devuelto por el query que estas poniendo en el datasource. Por eso es el error.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @reekeecast necesitamos ver la definición del `GridView` es posible que por ahí vaya el problema

Comment: acabo de corregir la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varios problemas:

**1.** En la configuración las propiedades `DataTextField` y `DataTextField` hacen referencia a `idMateria`, los cuales no existen en tu sentencia.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="idMateria" 
    DataValueField="idMateria">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**2.** En tu sentencia solo retornas el nombre de la asignatura y no retornas la columna `CodigoAsignatura` con el alias `idMateria`.

```
SELECT AsignaturaNombre
FROM Asignatura
WHERE CodigoAsignatura =
      (
          SELECT [idMateria]
          FROM [Permisos]
          WHERE ([idProfesor] = 19398676)
          UNION
          SELECT [idMateria]
          FROM [Permisos]
          WHERE ([idAlumno] = 19398676)
      );
```

Asimismo, internamente te debe estar generando el error:

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

---

**Para solucionar**

Actualiza tu sentencia:

```
SELECT CodigoAsignatura [idMateria]
FROM Asignatura
WHERE CodigoAsignatura IN
      (
          SELECT [idMateria]
          FROM [Permisos]
          WHERE ([idProfesor] = 19398676)
          UNION
          SELECT [idMateria]
          FROM [Permisos]
          WHERE ([idAlumno] = 19398676)
      );
```